# What's the right tool for this job?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to nest simple programs within a Google Sheets, similar to how you would with Visual Basic for Applications in Excel? Or alternatively a simple = syntax using regex, if there is a way to do that in Google Sheets?

I want to take a list of multiple names (name1, name2, name3) in a single cell from across multiple identical sheets and transpose them to another sheet within the same spreadsheet, check for duplicates and ignore capitals, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for an easy answer to a composite problem.  To solve this, I would split the job into separate chunks:

1. Split the input cell content into
   different cells. As it is unclear
   how this format is, I cannot advice
   on any specific method. Check out
   ImportRange function or similar.
2. Transpose them. use `=TRANSPOSE(area)`
3. Remova duplicates, use `=UNIQUE(area)`

Check [the Google Spreadsheet function list](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82712) for details.

Nest them: `=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:C15))`.

`LOWER` cannot be used in this nest as it works with only text input, not array input. Although you can use it for the first input cell.

Comment: This gave a good practical response to a rather vague question, thanks.